# An extra </p> is appearing in my source code--how do I diagnose the source?

Tags: html

On [my page](http://kabultec.org/dev/media-and-awards/) I've inserted some simple HTML via the text editor:

```
<div class="box box-tv">
<img class="logo-ma" src="http://kabultec.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/logo-nbc.svg"/>
<img class="logo-ma" src="http://kabultec.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/logo-nbc.svg"/>
<div class="logo-ma"></div>
<div class="logo-ma"></div>
</div>
```

But when I view the front-end source code, an extra `</p>` appears after the second `<img>` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6qEv.jpg)).  How can I determine the cause of this `</p>`?

- I have searched my source code for a potential opening `<p>` tag that I forgot to close, but none exists.
- I have also tried disabling auto-insertion of `<br>` and `<p>` tags, by adding code to functions.php.

  add_action('spacious_before_body_content', 'nobrp');
  function nobrp() {
      if (is_page('232')) {
          remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
          remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
          function wpse_wpautop_nobr( $content ) {
              return wpautop( $content, false );
          }
          add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_wpautop_nobr' );
          add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse_wpautop_nobr' );
      }
  }
- I also added code to remove `<p>` tags around `<img>` tags ([see here](https://interconnectit.com/blog/2011/06/16/how-to-remove-p-tags-from-images-in-wordpress/)).  But that did not resolve my issue either.

The motivation for removing the `</p>` is that I plan to add more images to this page, inside a flex container, so they are laid out a specific way on the page.  The extra `</p>` is causing elements to not align as expected.

Workarounds are appreciated, but if possible, I am most interested in determining the cause of this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used these in a template to remove all p tags from an editor:

```
remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');

// This is where the content of the editor was written out by the template

add_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop'); //add back the filter 
//so it doesn't mess with other stuff
```

Also you could try deleting the line break between the images. It will look ugly in the editor but may solve the issue.

Edit: I just realized this is for acf field, but the ACF plugin could also solve your problem this way...